# Could I run a Zepp antenna from a telegraph pole underneath a mains cable?

Tags: antenna

I'm new to the forum, and I've been advised that this is a good place to get experienced opinion. I lived in a three storey terraced house in Mid Wales. It is terraced on three sides with the house on one side being taller than mine. There are also two very tall solid chapels  on each side of the road  a few metres away. I have access to a small area at the rear which is about two and a half metres by 2 and a half metres.

I have a vertical sandpiper on the roof but this has limited success because of the taller buildings around my house., I also have a 69ft zeppelin aerial which runs from the guttering at one corner of the roof, (about 30 ft high) passing above  my neighbours smaller Cottage and garden to a plastic downpipe on one of the chapels at the bottom of my neighbour's garden (about 20ft up).. Unfortunately because of the proximity of the very old sound system the HF can interfere with the sound system in the chapel even on qrp

There is a telegraph pole about 10 ft away from the chapel and the same distance from my house which is accessible. I could move the end of the Zeppelin to the telegraph pole. This would mean that it would be 3 or 4 ft down from a mains distribution cable that comes to my house. The Zeppelin and the mains cable would not be exactly parallel and over the length of the Zeppelin they would end up about 6 feet apart at the building..

I would only have to move the farthest end of the Zeppelin. At the moment the cables are about 10 feet apart at the far end and about 6 feet apart at the house end and I don't experience any interference.

Would moving the Zepp to the pole present any interference problems for either my reception or the local dwellings via the electricity network please

The attached pic is not too clear, but you can get an idea of the layout.

Keith.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do it. Power lines carry noise from all the houses attached to them, and with your antenna in such close proximity you'll probably hear all of it.

Likewise, when transmitting you'll likely couple a fair bit of RF into the power line. That could cause even more interference with your neighbors.

It's also a safety hazard. If that power line should fall and come into contact with the antenna you may be in for a surprise.

It's probably also illegal.